# Creating a simple data set to train a neural network for printed text OCR

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, data-science, training-data

I want to train a neural net to recognize text only a single font on paper (Times Roman). Can I get away with only a single training sample for each character?

My rationale is that the font would not vary as opposed to a hand written one.  The only thing that may change is the angle, and brightness which I can clean up before inferring it after my model is trained.  Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where your input is coming from.  If the input is going to be screenshots and the font is always the same, (including font-size, boldness, etc.) and always in the same colours. Then you can probably get away with only one set.

If you are dealing with input from scanners or photos then you probably will end up with partially cut-off characters, warped characters from bends in the page or off-angle 3d photography, smudges on the page, and millions of other minor differences.  You can try to clean them up before sending it to OCR, but your cleaner function will need to be more advanced than your OCR function for that to work so it's probably easier to just use a bunch of different learning sets for your OCR neural net.